# Percentage calculation, doesn't give the exact value

Tags: php, percentage

I have an issue with a progress bar formed by a table and an image as bar.

this is the table formation

```
<td><?php echo $img1; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $img2; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $img3; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $img4; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $img5; ?></td>
```

and this is the php code:

```
<?php
$value = 10000 //this value is obtained by SQL
$bar1 = 2600 //is the value of the first bar, obtained by SQL
$bar2 = 9950 //is the value of the second bar, obtained by SQL
$bar3 = 13010 //same as before
$bar4 = 17500 //same as before
$bar5 = 19500 //same as before

if($value > 0) && ($value < $bar1) {
$percent = ($value / $bar1) *100;
$bar1 = '<img src="progress.png" width="'.$percent.'" />';
}

if($value >= $bar1) {
$percent = '100';
$bar1 = '<img src="reached.png" width="'.$percent.'" />';
?>
```

And for the first bar is ok, work as intended, if the value is minor of $bar1 amount, then it show it as progress, if instead, it is higher than the $bar1 amount, it shows it as reached.

The Issues start with the other bars, taking an example the bar 3:

```
<?php 
if($value > $bar2) && ($value < bar3) {
$percent = ($value / $bar3) *100;
$bar3 = '<img src="progress.png" width="'.$percent.'" />';
}
>?
```

Obviosly the response of the percent is: 76 percent, and it almost full fill all the bar. The fact is the previous bar is setted as 9950, and the value is 10000, so on the $bar3 (which is 13010) should be showen something like (between 30 percent), and not 76 percent.

The purpose is simple:

When the $value, it fill the $bar1, then it moves on and starts filling the $bar2, if this one has been filled too, then it moves to the $bar3.. this until the $value is not enough anymore to fill or it reaches the last $bar5.

However, this is happening "wrong".

What I mistaken in this?

Comment: I don't understand it, you are doing always ($values / $barN) * 100, but you don't want it, if you want the difference from previous bar why you don't do something like ($value/ ($bar3-$bar2)) * 100?

Comment: I solved by adding: $n = $value - $bar2  and then:   $percent = ($n / $bar3)*100;    this way work as intended

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by changing the operation:

```
$bar3_reduced = $bar3 - $bar2;
$new = $value - $bar2; //detract from the value the previous bar amount
$percent = ($new / $bar3_reduced)*100;
```

So now it compares only the progress on the "new" bar, instead of counting them all.